# slidedrawer from left to right in android

Tags: android

Can anyone give a simple example on how to make a slidedrawer in android from left to right
I searched the internet very much but couldn't get a proper solution.
waiting for your replies.
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use Below Code for horizontal sliding drawer.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#55000000">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" - Button - "/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" - Button - "/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" - Button - "/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" - Button - "/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" - Button - "/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" - Button - "/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</FrameLayout>
```

Use below example link for Reference.

[SlidingDrawer in horizontal - 1](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/slidingdrawer-in-horizontal.html)

[SlidingDrawer in horizontal - 2](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622)

Comment: **I have made this before I want slide to be from left to right**

Comment: ok got the answer from your second link http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622